# Nokogiri says versions of Libxml2 above 2.9.0 are broken, is it?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, libxml2

The message on installation says so, but I can't find any reference to it. "are currently ***known*** to be broken", but known *by whom*, and what *is* the problem? I've checked the Nokogiri code base and issue log, but I can't find the reference to this.

Here's the (relevant parts of the) message Nokogiri (v1.6.3.1 in this case) gives:

```
IMPORTANT!  Nokogiri builds and uses a packaged version of libxml2.

If this is a concern for you and you want to use the system library
instead, abort this installation process and reinstall nokogiri as
follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

However, note that nokogiri does not necessarily support all versions
of libxml2.

For example, libxml2-2.9.0 and higher are currently known to be broken
and thus unsupported by nokogiri, due to compatibility problems and
XPath optimization bugs.
```

Comment: The XPath optimization bug is probably [this issue](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=695699). This was my fault but it is [fixed in the current 2.9.2 release](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml2/commit/?id=b4bcba23f64b71105514875f165a63d4cc720609).

Comment: @nwellnhof Kudos to you for taking responsibility like that, and thanks for the info. Mystery 33% solved! Now to find out what the "compatibility problems" are, and why ***known*** is so hard to ***know*** :-)

Comment: Hi Guys, I'm using yosemite and this is happening to me. Any help???

Comment: @olleh could it be related to [this issue](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1214) ?

Answer (score 1):

There might be two ways:
1. use system libraries as it indicate:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
```

2. it might be grep problem, indicated [here](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/935), and you might be able to get over it by a shell command (assuming using Bash):

`export GREP_OPTIONS="--color=auto"`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question so I can't give it the tick, but it may be helpful to others so best to leave it here.